# How do I pass only related prop when using map function in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, map-function

I have a ReviewList component that maps through a database and populates the page with a list of reviews. Within each review, I am also passing an Edit modal component, in which I try to pass props through. The problem I am facing is trying to pass only the props appropriate to the specific review. Instead, it is passing the props of every review being mapped, so when trying to edit the review in the Edit modal component, it always modifies the first review since it is the first in the list of props. For example, when I console.log the _id prop, I receive the _id of every review being mapped, instead of just the _id of the specific review whose edit button was clicked.

ReviewList component:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import Edit from "../Edit/index";
import Auth from "../../utils/auth";

const ReviewList = ({ reviews, profileReviewEdit }) => {
  const [showEditModal, setShowEditModal] = useState(false);

  const reload = () => window.location.reload();

  if (!reviews.length) {
    return (
      <h1 className='pageText'>No Reviews Yet</h1>
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="containter center">

        {reviews && reviews.map((review) => (
          
          <div className='row bloc-box'>

            <div className='col-3'>
              <Link to={`/gamepage/${review.gameId}`}>
                <img src={`${review.gameCoverUrl}`}
                  fluid
                  thumbnail
                  width={200}
                />
              </Link>


              <Link to={`/gamepage/${review.gameId}`}>
                <h5 className='game-title'>{review.gameTitle}</h5>
              </Link>

            </div>

            <div className='col'>

              <h3 className='col'>
                <p className='review-title'>{review.title}</p>
              </h3>


              <div className="pl-3">
                <p className="username-link">
                  Written by: <Link
                    to={`/profile/${review.username}`}
                    style={{ fontWeight: 700 }}>
                    {review.username}
                  </Link>{' '} on {review.createdAt}
                </p>
              </div>

              <div>
                <div className="col-9">
                  <h4 className='review-text'>{review.reviewBody}</h4>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className='col-9'>

                {[...Array(parseInt(`${review.rating}`))].map((star, i) => {
                  const ratingValue = i + 1;

                  return (
                    <label>
                      <input
                        type='radio'
                        name='rating'
                        value={review.rating}
                      />
                      <FontAwesomeIcon className='star'
                        icon='star'
                        size='lg'
                        color={review.rating ? '#ffc107' : '#e4e5e9'}
                      />
                    </label>

                  )
                })}
              </div>
              <p className='small-title'> {review.rating}/5 Stars </p>

            </div>

            <div>
              {Auth.loggedIn(), profileReviewEdit &&
                <div>
                  <Button variant="outline-warning" size='sm' onClick={() => setShowEditModal(true)}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="edit" color="#FEBE10" size="lg" />Edit</Button>{' '}
                </div>}
            </div>



            <div >

              <Modal
                size="lg"
                show={showEditModal}
                onHide={() => setShowEditModal(false)}
                onExit={reload}
              >
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                  <Modal.Title>Edit Review</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                  <Edit
                    handleModalClose={() => setShowEditModal(false)}
                    _id={review._id}
                    reviewTitle={review.title}
                    reviewBody={review.reviewBody}
                    setShowEditModal={setShowEditModal}
                  />
                </Modal.Body>
              </Modal>
            </div>

          </div>

        ))}

      </div>

    </>
  )
};

export default ReviewList;
```

Edit component:

```
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { EDIT_REVIEW, DELETE_REVIEW } from "../../utils/mutations";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

const Edit = ({ _id, reviewTitle, reviewBody, setShowEditModal }) => {
  console.log(_id);
  const [ editReview ] = useMutation(EDIT_REVIEW);
  const [ deleteReview ] = useMutation(DELETE_REVIEW);

  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [titleCharacterCount, setTitleCharacterCount] = useState(0);

  const [editBody, setEditBody] = useState("");
  const [editBodyCharacterCount, SetEditBodyCharacterCount] = useState(0);
  console.log(editBody);

  const [rating, setRating] = useState(null);
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(null);

  console.log()

  const handleTitleChange = (event) => {
    if (event.target.value.length <= 30) {
      setTitle(event.target.value);
      setTitleCharacterCount(event.target.value.length);
    }
  };

  const handleEditBodyChange = (event) => {
    if (event.target.value.length <= 1000) {
      setEditBody(event.target.value);
      SetEditBodyCharacterCount(event.target.value.length);
    }
  };

  const handleFormSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // reviewBody = editBody;

    try {
      await editReview({
        variables: { _id:_id, title:title, reviewBody:editBody, rating:rating },
      });

      // clear form value
      setTitle("");
      setTitleCharacterCount(0);
      setEditBody("");
      SetEditBodyCharacterCount(0);
      setShowEditModal(false);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  const handleDelete = async ( _id ) => {
    console.log(_id)
    try {
      await deleteReview({
        variables: { _id },
      });
      setShowEditModal(false);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

  const StarRating = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        {[...Array(5)].map((star, i) => {
          const ratingValue = i + 1;

          return (
            <label>
              <input 
                type='radio' 
                name='rating' 
                value={ratingValue} 
                onClick={() => setRating(ratingValue)}
              />
              <FontAwesomeIcon className='star'
                icon='star'
                size='2x'
                color= {ratingValue <= (hover || rating) ? '#ffc107' : '#e4e5e9'}
                onMouseEnter={() => setHover(ratingValue)}
                onMouseLeave={() => setHover(null)}
              />
            </label>
          )
        })}
        <h5> {rating}/5 Stars </h5>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        className="flex-row justify-center justify-space-between-md align-stretch"
        onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
      >
        <textarea
          placeholder={reviewTitle}
          value={title}
          className="form-input col-12 col-md-9"
          onChange={handleTitleChange}
        ></textarea>
        <p className={`m-0 ${titleCharacterCount === 30 ? "text-error" : ""}`}>
          Character Count: {titleCharacterCount}/30
        </p>

        <textarea
          placeholder={reviewBody}
          value={editBody}
          className="form-input col-12 col-md-9"
          onChange={handleEditBodyChange}
        ></textarea>
        <p
          className={`m-0 ${editBodyCharacterCount === 1000 ? "text-error" : ""
            }`}
        >
          Character Count: {editBodyCharacterCount}/1000
        </p>
        <StarRating />

        {/* {error && <span className="ml-2">Something went wrong...</span>} */}
        <button className="btn btn-success col-12 col-md-3" type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
      <button className="btn btn-danger mt-1 col-12 col-md-3" type="button" onClick={() => handleDelete(_id)}>
        Delete Review
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Edit;
```

Answer (score 0):

The architecture for the whole thing a bit messy. I am trying to solve the problem as well as the architecture for your mentioned problem. But always try to keep your components more precise.

***First***

You should not render modal for each review instead create a single modal and on edit click store the review in a state and pass that review to the modal.

take a new hook

```
const [currentReview, setCurrentReview] = useState(null);
```

***Secondly***

Now `Edit` button click set the review like this

```
    <Button variant="outline-warning" size='sm' onClick={() => setCurrentReview(review)}>
         <FontAwesomeIcon icon="edit" color="#FEBE10" size="lg" />Edit
    </Button>
```

***Thirdly***

In your modal pass the currentReview as props ad to open the Modal use it like this

```js
<Modal
  size="lg"
  show={Boolean(currentReview)}
  onHide={() => setCurrentReview(null)}
  onExit={reload}
>
  <Modal.Header closeButton>
    <Modal.Title>Edit Review</Modal.Title>
  </Modal.Header>
  <Modal.Body>
    <Edit
      handleModalClose={() => setCurrentReview(null)}
      _id={currentReview._id}
      reviewTitle={currentReview.title}
      reviewBody={currentReview.reviewBody}
    />
  </Modal.Body>
</Modal>
```

Pass any thing else you need as props in Edit modal.